# what the best practice in REST to append or delete to a list

Tags: rest, django

Suppose

```js
GET /users/<id>

{
  user_id : "asdasdas-da-sd-asd-as-d",
  firs_name : "asdasd",
  ....
  department : [{
      id : "asdas-da-sdasd-asd",
      name : "asdasdasdasd",
      ...
      },]
}​
```

To add a new department for that user first create a department by:

```
POST /departments/
```

Then we use `PATCH` with department **id**

```js
PATCH /users/<id>

{
   department : [
    "asdas-da-sdasd-asd", // #Existing department ids
    "new-one-id"     // # New ID
 ]
}
```

Is this method ok?

What is the best way to manage these in API side and considering the easiness in client side?

Or follow something like:

```
POST/PUT to  /user/<id>/departments/[<id>]
```

to add/update the department

or

```
DELETE to /user/<id>/departments/<id>
```

to remove that dept from list

- we do not use `DELETE`, but only make the field *active* using `PATCH` or `PUT`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### To list the user departments

Use `GET /users/<id>/departments`, instead of returning this info in the `users` resource.

Doing so allow the below topics to work well in the most RESTful manner - the `user-departments` relation will *always* be available under `/users/<id>/departments`, instead of sometimes available under `/users/<id>`.

#### To assign an department to a user

The best design, IMO, is a `PUT /users/<id>/departments/<id>`:

- The `PUT` method is idempotent - if you do it more than once, the result will always be the same;
- By declaring in the URL the department you want to add, the request body can be empty - *unless* you need to parameterize this relation somehow;
- Be sure to always return an `200 OK` (instead of a `201 Created` the first time), so the request is always the same

#### To remove an department from a user

Keep doing `DELETE /users/<id>/departments/<id>`.

It doesn't matter what your server is doing (deleting or flagging the `user-departments` relation).
The proposal of the `DELETE` method is to make something unavailable from now on.